# Vanilla JS/HTML: best practice to connect html object to internal data-model/array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a thumbnail view that has x-items that are internally stored in an array.
After the initial request there is no more server communication so everything is handled in the browser afterwards.

In my current solution I give each html thumbnail item the id of their corresponding index inside my internal data model, so that after a click on a thumbnail I know which data to load.

I thought that was a nice idea until I tried to implement the delete operation, so it is possible to delete any item on any position and also to drag and drop thumbnail items around.

So in my current solution i would need to run through every single html thumbnail item after every update to adjust the indexes, which is not a very nice solution.

I do not believe I will ever run in performance problems because it is very doubtful that the thumbnail will contain more then 100 items but I wonder if where is a better solution or a best practice to make it nicer.

I can't influence the datamodel/array in any way or form so a map with uids is not an option, also can't use any framework so a vanilla solution would be required.

```
<button class="thumbNailItem" id="tni#5"><h3>BOLD</h3><p>My Description</p></button>
```

```
this.deleteStep = function() {
  let thumbParent = document.getElementById('thumbNailParent');
  this.curTC.testSteps.splice(this.curStep.index, 1);

  thumbParent.removeChild(thumbNailParent.children[this.curStep.index]);

  //would need to implement loop to correct all 'tni#ids'

  if (this.curStep.index <= thumbParent.children.length) {
    thumbParent.children[this.curStep.index].click();
  }
```

Comment: Could you show us what you currently have by any chance?

Comment: Where's your code though?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: just use a template and re-render the whole thing each time, like react does, but without the vdom.

Comment: I can't use any template - just simple and pure vanilla, html JS without any template/framework - basics only

Comment: You can use templates with vanilla JS...

Comment: @Ruvi You may want to look into [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: Ah, these kind of templates, now I understand. I thought you mean something like handlebars.
But how is that supposed to work. The indexes are coming from the position of the element in the  array.
The elements inside the array do not know their own index.

Comment: @Ruvi Take a look at the answer I've provided, hope that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explained

Considering we have very little idea as to what it is **exactly** that you're looking for, here's a *simple* enough way in which you can simply handle data, some events and some rendering, using nothing more than native JavaScript.

If you need some documentation to understand this code, I strongly suggest you take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), I mean I'd imagine that you can make sense of it for the most part. As stated previously in the comments, to achieve this, I've simply used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to handle how the HTML is being rendered.

There are many approaches that you could use to *essentially* solve the same problem(s), but this one in my opinion is clean, clear and concise as to what is going on.

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  
  // Just some dummy data for the time being. 
  let data = [
    {name: "Jack", age: 18},
    {name: "Leah", age: 32},
    {name: "Jay", age: 45}
  ];
  
  // Simple reference to the app div.
  const app = document.getElementById("app");
  
  // How you want to handle the click event for each button. 
  const handler = e => {
    data.splice(e.target.id, 1);
    render();
  };
  
  // A simple function to handle dispatching the events. 
  const dispatchEvents = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".profile button").forEach(btn => btn.onclick = handler);
  };
  
  // A simple render method. 
  const render = () => {
    app.innerHTML = data.map((o, i) => `<div class="profile">
      <p class="username">Name: ${o.name}</p>
      <p class="userage">Age: ${o.age}</p>
      <button id=${i}>DELETE</button>
    </div>`).join("");
    dispatchEvents();
  };
  
  // Initial render. 
  render();
})();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps.